# Listview: Load images dependent on values in sql database (from the notepad tutorial)

Tags: android, sql, listview, android-image

I have done the notepad tutorial of the google webside. There are these tree strings:

```
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
```

I only put the values "0", "1", "2", "3"  in my KEY_TITLE. Instead of showing the strings in a TextView of my Listview, I want to show the images from this array:

```
private int icons[] = new int[] {R.drawable.icon1, 
R.drawable.icon2, R.drawable.icon3, R.drawable.icon4};
```

e.g. If KEY_TITLE ist "0" I want to show the the image icon1. etc....

Now I have the problem, that the SimpleCursorAdapter can only map to TextViews. How can I tell the SimpleCursorAdapter, that it has to map the string values to the number of icons in my icons[]-string?

Can anybody help me, how to write a new SimpleCursorAdapter? Or is it not necessary?

```
    private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.image};

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi FelixA why a SimpleAdapter?
If i may make a suggestion switch to CustomBasAdapter, it gices you more options to tweak for later use, also adding icons, images etc.
Follow the description on [this](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html) site to make the adapter.
You can later on tweak it and add the icons pictures etc.

```
public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results, int[] images) {
 super();
   mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   this.images = images;
   searchArrayList = results;
  }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewHolder holder;

   if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);

    holder.imgViewLogo =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
 ....
 convertView.setTag(holder);
} 

 ....
 holder.imgViewLogo.setImageResource(images[position%4]); // 4 icons to add
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom layout, and override bindView